# Module ag-grid-angular/main has no exported member AgGridNg2.ts

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I installed ag-grid into my Angular 7 app and am following the ag-grid tutorial on [Enable Selection for ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/#enable-selection). When I try to import `AgGridNg2` I get `Module ag-grid-angular/main has no exported member AgGridNg2.ts`. I can only assume the docs for this plugin are out of date. What do I need to fix to make this work? Here is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridNg2;
      columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', sortable: true, filter: true, checkboxSelection: true },
        {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', sortable: true, filter: true },
        {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', sortable: true, filter: true }
    ];

rowData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rowData = this.http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9');
  }

}
```

EDIT: Here is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webapplication12",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run WebApplication12:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.5",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "7.1.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^21.0.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.0.1",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "^8.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.6.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~11.10.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of ag-grid are you using ? Could you shared the package.json file here.

Comment: @abd995 I've added package.json. Looks like I'm on version 21

Answer (score 7):

Try to use **AgGridAngular** instead **AgGridNg2** like this

```
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
...
@ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridAngular;
```

Comment: AgGridNg2 is deprecated, The correct way is using AgGridAngular. Please check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-ng2

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular 8 and @ViewChild('agGrid') expected 2 arguments (but got 1), so what worked for me is simply :

```
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
...
private agGrid: AgGridAngular;
```